# The External Hard Drive fell and I can't access storage . Anyway to fix?

Tags: hard-drive

1. When I plugin the USB cable the device light is on.
2. A window pops up and says installing expansion after two to three seconds the        window gets closed.
3. The portable drive is not shown in the disk management and in My computer.
4. Portable drive is seagate expansion 1tb/USB 3.0

Comment: Does it show in Device Manager?

Comment: @qasdfdsaq  no, it is not shown in Device Manager.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, the drop might have damaged the drive physically. Mechanical HDDs are rather sensitive like that, and it's highly unlikely that you'd be able to fix it. I'd recommend you to test it using your hard drive manufacturer's diagnostic tool and check up on the health and SMART status. If you also have access to another computer, check how the external HDD is detected there as well.

Comment: @: Even diagnostic tool are not detecting the external drive ,tried in seatools

Comment: I'd suggest you to check the warranty of the external drive on your manufacturer's website. If it's still covered, you should RMA it and get a replacement from them. However, if it's out of warranty, you could try getting the HDD out of the enclosure and plugging it internally via SATA or a docking station. Something that will supply it with more power than a USB port. Do you have any important data that is not backed up stored on the external HDD?

Answer (score 0):

IIRC Seagate expansion drives are 3.5 inch drives, and probably have a proper 3.5 inch drive in there

If the drive is out of warranty, or since its probably voided anyway, crack it open anyway.

Reseat the drive and test. If it works, close it up. If it dosen't try it connected directly over sata. If it still fails, your drive is probably dead.